# Chrome extension providing a file name while downloading string to file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

bg.js

```
var blob = new Blob(['dummy content'], {type: 'text/plain'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileName = fileNamePrefix + (new Date()).getTime();
console.log('debug: fileNamePrefix: ' + fileNamePrefix);
console.log('debug: fileName: ' + fileName + '.txt');
chrome.downloads.download({
  url: url,
  filename: fileName + '.txt',
  saveAs: false
}, function(id) {
  console.log('debug: download callback: id: ' + id);
});
```

console output

```
bg.js:11 debug: fileNamePrefix: dummy-prefix--
bg.js:12 debug: fileName: dummy-prefix--1514054609088.txt
bg.js:18 debug: download callback: id: 39
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "DemoExt",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "16.0.884",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "downloads", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {"scripts": ["bg.js"], "persistent": false},
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

why are the file name's all Ids, instead of the file name I'm providing?

```
Robs-Mac:~ rob$ ls Downloads/
31f4efac-2fc9-40e5-bb0b-c5aaa95d1212.txt
49833a51-e3a1-4c5a-a2c6-1f209eae7a34.txt
4b045f60-7359-42fe-89ae-df09f42a6777.txt
6f138ef2-f9da-4783-98d2-012a0fea533d.txt
6fb5f779-385e-4516-989c-aed2691e21b7.txt
```

Comment: `console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);` gives `undefined`

Answer (score -2):

I didn't use chrome extension but i did the same in different way hope this help you. Here is the code that i used

```
var blob = new Blob(['dummy content'], {type: 'text/plain'});
var fileName = "dummyprefix.txt";
var pom = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(pom);
pom.style = "display: none";
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
pom.setAttribute('href', url);
pom.setAttribute('download', fileName);
pom.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', pom.download, pom.href].join(':');
pom.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

You might need to add checks for Internet Explorer though.